# NVIDIA Data Types

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia, nvidia-deepstream

What is the difference between Frame Meta, Object Meta and User Meta? Please explain in layman terms. I know they are nested and looked up at the docs but was still unable to decipher it.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/metropolis/deepstream/python-api/PYTHON_API/NvDsMeta/NvDsMeta_toc.html), and for further explanation you can take a look at sample apps, providing by deepstream (e.g. test4, written in C - there are frame, object and user metadata presented.